# How to construct search filter for a java ldap search api ,when object name has single or double quote in it

Tags: java, ldap

I have an object, `cn=abc"and'def` in the directory. I am using the Java search API:

```
public LDAPSearchResults search(java.lang.String base,
    int scope,
    java.lang.String filter,
    java.lang.String[] attrs,
    boolean typesOnly,
    LDAPSearchConstraints cons)
    throws LDAPException
```

I tried giving the search filter as `abc"and'def` and also as `abc\"and\'def`. Both return:

> > Bad search filter

Please help me as to how to construct the search filter when the object name has single or double quote in it.

Answer (score 5):

The entire LDAP search filter must be a valid [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) string. There five (5) values that, should they appear in a search filter, must be escaped using a backslash `\` and the two-digit hexadecimal code for the character being escaped. The values that must be escaped are `*`, `(`, `)`, `\`, and the null byte `0`; therefore the `"` and the `'` are legal and valid characters in the search filter. In a language like Java that encloses a string literal between `"` characters, the `"` character appearing as part of string literal must be escaped.

In one example, you list the filter with a backslash `\` character in the filter. A backslash must be escaped in the filter using a backslash and the hexadecimal code for backslash, for example, `"(cn=abc\5c\"and'def)'"`. In the other example, you list as the filter `"(cn=abc"and'def)"` which is in fact a legal search filter - ignoring the fact that the inner `"` is not escaped as it must be for compilation.

By way of example, I created an object in a directory at my localhost listening on port 1389 with prefix or naming context `dc=example,dc=com` using the following LDIF:

```
dn: cn=abc"and'def,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
cn: abc"and'def
sn: whatever
```

I wrote a Java class to search for the entry, throwing an assertion error if it should not be found:

```
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.Filter;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnection;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPException;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.SearchScope;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.SearchResult;

public final class BSFilter {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    try {
      Filter searchFilter =
        Filter.create("cn=abc\"and'def");
      LDAPConnection connection =
        new LDAPConnection("localhost",1389);
      SearchResult searchResult =
        connection.search("dc=example,dc=com",SearchScope.ONE,
                          searchFilter,"1.1");
      assert(searchResult.getSearchEntries().size() == 0);
    } catch(LDAPException lex) {
      lex.printStackTrace();
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

This class compiles and throws an assertion error as expected because the entry for which it searches does in fact exist. See [RFC 4515](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4515) for information regarding the search filter. The LDAPSDK used is the excellent [SDK](http://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/) from UnboundID. Notice that the `"` character is escaped in the filter so that the class will compile, but that has nothing to do with the filter text itself.

Answer (score 2):

Use the force of the filter to handle escaping for your. Something like:

```
"(&(objectClass=user)(cn={0}))"
```

Answer (score 1):

I use JNDI and one of the [search() overloads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/directory/DirContext.html#search%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20javax.naming.directory.SearchControls%29) that take a `filterArgs' argument. Does all the escaping required for you.